# Weird behaviour of if(x instanceof X)

Tags: java, class, inheritance, instanceof

I have a class `PartA` and a class `PartB` which is a derived class of `PartA`.
I have a list of type `PartA` which holds both parts a and b.
And I need to determine which kind of class it actually is when I loop through it.
But if I do this:

```
for (PartA i : parts) {
    if (i instanceof PartA) {
        //some logic
    }
```

It will still give true regardless of which class it actually is: a or b.

Am I doing something wrong or if not, what can I do to acheive desired result?

Comment: Please refer some good java books to understand inheritance and instanceof operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is by design.
Instance of `B` are also instances of `A`.

You want

```
if (i.getClass() == A.class)
```

Comment: @NewProger I think he meant `(i.getClass() == PartA.class)`.

Comment: @cdhowie that's what I did obviously, but it gave me that error.

Answer (score 6):

Instances of `PartB` *are also* instances of `PartA`.  Always check for the most derived type first.  (Read `instanceof X` as "is an instance of `X` or a derived type of `X`.")

Or, better yet, use polymorphism to your advantage -- can this logic be moved into a method of `PartA` that you could override on `PartB`?  Then you would not have to actually test the type of the object, you would just let virtual method dispatch figure that out for you.

Comment: Usually I do use polymorphism, but this is for assignment and this is the first time I use instanceof thing. So I was a little confused as to how it works. Thank you for clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here `instanceof` is behaving as specified in [JLS15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) . According to which:

> At run time, the result of the instanceof operator is true if the
>   value of the RelationalExpression is not null and **the reference could
>   be cast (§15.16) to the ReferenceType** without raising a
>   ClassCastException. Otherwise the result is false.

In your case `i` is the reference which is the sub type of reference type `PartA`. Therefore it is always returning `true`. You should use:

```
 if((i.getClass().getName()).equals(A.class.getName()))
```

Comment: I see, it is just first time I use "instanceof". So I was a little confused as to how it works. Thank you for clear explanation. I should have read java doc more carefuly...

Comment: Comparing class names seems unnecessary.

Comment: I think it is a good solution since it is really simple and does solve the problem. But I'm sure there could be other ways to do it even for example as was given in other answers.

Comment: Any reason to compare the class _names_ instead of the classes themselves?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes .Given that `i` is the object of subclass `ChildA` and also is the reference of `ChildA` .. `i.getClass() == A.class` is invalid comparision. If you do show It is showing compile time error: incomparable types: `java.lang.Class<capture#734 of ? extends ChildA> and java.lang.Class<A>`.. Where `ChildA` is the subClass of class `A`. I think that comparing the name of class will work for all cases..

Answer (score 1):

Given your inheritance of `PartB` from `PartA`, a `PartB` *is* a `PartA`, so `a instanceof PartA` will always be `true`.  To tell them apart, you'll need to test if it's a `PartB`.

Comment: I see. I was just thinking it tests for exact this class you are asking it to, but as you and other guys explained it behaves differently to what I expected.

Comment: Yes, I had the correct explanation for why it always returned `true` too, but @SLaks and @cdhowie have better solutions.